# Flutter drop down button

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

hello how can I create this kind of drop down button thank you

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sN9pi.jpg)

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/accordion/example

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ExpansionTile` widget:

```
ExpansionTile(
  title: Text(
    "Your Title",
  ),
  children: [
    ListTile(
      title: Text(
        "Expanded descriptions",
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```